# Why am I not able to add a JPanel to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I would like to draw something like this weather map:

[image: Weather map]

On the top, there is a header which contains information (title, ...) and below there is the actual picture. I tried to model the program like the following but it does not show the image of the weather map.

Later I would like to be able to resize the whole weather map (title and picture).

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Window meteoWindow = new Window();
    meteoWindow.setVisible(true);
}
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    Container c;
    WeatherMap wm1;

    public Window() {
        c = getContentPane();

        // Loading weather maps
        wm1 = new WeatherMap("http://www.link-to-image.com/weatherimage.png");

        // ---
        c.add(wm1);

        setTitle("Meteoview Alpha");
        setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class WeatherMap extends JPanel {
    private DescriptionPanel descriptionPanel;
    private ImagePanel imagePanel;
    private WeatherImage weatherImage;

    public WeatherMap(String urlPath) {
        imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        descriptionPanel = new DescriptionPanel("Wetterkarte 1");
        weatherImage = new WeatherImage("http://www.linktoweatherimage/image.png");
    }
}


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DescriptionPanel extends JPanel {
    private String name;
    private JLabel nameLabel;

    public DescriptionPanel(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        nameLabel = new JLabel(name, JLabel.LEFT);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(nameLabel);
    }
}

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5));

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.linktoimage/image.png"));
            System.out.println("Successfully read...");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried it with a few different approaches, but nothing really works. Can you help me to model this? (JPanel on JPanel, or BufferedImage on JPanel, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
    descriptionPanel = new DescriptionPanel("Wetterkarte 1");
    weatherImage = new WeatherImage("http://www.modellzentrale.de/WRF4km/12Z/15h/RR3h_eu.png");
```

You create 3 components, but you don't add the components to the panel.

Not really sure what you are trying to do since you attempt to read the same image twice, so I don't know why you have a "WeatherImage" and an "ImagePanel".

So I will just suggest you first try something like the following to understand how to use a panel with a layout manager.

```
imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
descriptionPanel = new DescriptionPanel("Wetterkarte 1");

setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
add(descriptionPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also, then is no need to create a custom painting to simply paint an image at it actual size. You can just add the Image to a JLabel by using an ImageIcon:

```
image = ImageIO.read(…);
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(image) );
```

Now you add the label to any panel you want.